# Javascript Code reordering with Ajax sync:false

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a button click event that initiates an ajax call, and I need the ajax call to be synchronous so I set async:false.  I want to provide feedback to the user so they know that the ajax call is happening in the back.  So I have the following:

```
$('#ajaxBtn').on("click",function() {
    $('#ajaxBtn').html("processing ...");
    $.ajax({
        type: "Get",
        url: "example.php?data=test",
        async: false,
        success: function(){
            alert("success");
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("failure");
        }
    })
}
```

On Chrome (haven't tested on other browsers) When I click the button, everything freezes while the ajax call completes, however the text on the button doesn't update until the success alert pops up.  If I step through the code in the debugger it works as I would expect.  The text on the button changes before the ajax call initiates.

If I set Async: true it also seems to work as expected.  The text changes immediately and then I get to the success function.

Is Chrome reordering the ajax call to happen before the changing of the text?  Why am I seeing this?

Comment: Don't use `async: false`.  Instead, fix your code to handle async requests.  Promises can help.

Comment: This behavior is by design.  Sync actions block the UI thread.

Comment: From jQuery documentation: "Note that synchronous requests may temporarily lock the browser, disabling any actions while the request is active". Is pretty unclear why do you need to use a synchro call when is a good practice to avoid them.

Comment: @mart First, unless Chrome reorders the commands, I change the text BEFORE the ajax call.  Secondly, I don't want to use a Syncronous call, but I am doing it because this click submits a form, but only depending on the success of the ajax call.  I think that SLaks comment about Promises may help me avert this though.

Comment: Could you provide your code with the form to submit

Comment: `"false"` is a truthy value. Did you mean `false`?

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this.

```
$('#ajaxBtn').on("click",function() {

    $.ajax({
        type: "Get",
        url: "example.php?data=test",
        //note that I have removed the async: "false",
        beforeSend:function(){
             $('#ajaxBtn').html("processing ...");
        },
        success: function(){
            alert("success");
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("failure");
        }
    }).done(function(data){
        //submit your form here depending on which data is returned

    });
}
```

Comment: with async: false, even the beforeSend seems to not run.  Basically as soon as the ajax call is made the dom gets frozen.  This is apparently by design.